# Как воспроизвести последующие выбранные аудиофайлы?

Tags: c++, qtcreator, qmediaplayer

Каждый раз, когда я после запуска программы выбираю какой либо аудиофайл - он воспроизводится, но любой последующий выбранный аудиофайл из списка заново воспроизводит первую аудио.
При том, что сам "temp_audio_file.wav" корректно изменяется и в нём лежит выбранная аудио

```
void formWithAudio::on_listWidget_itemClicked(QListWidgetItem *item)
{

    QFile tmpFile("temp_audio_file.wav");
    QString nextSong = item->text();
    if (tmpFile.exists()) {
         tmpFile.remove();
         QFile tmpFile("temp_audio_file.wav");
         ObjectMediaPlayer->MP->stop();
    }
     query->exec("SELECT * FROM audioFiles WHERE filename = '" + nextSong + "'" );
     qDebug() << nextSong;
     query->first();

     QByteArray audioData = query->value("data").toByteArray();

     if (!tmpFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)) {
         qDebug() << "Ошибка создания временного файла";
         return;
     }
     tmpFile.write(audioData);
     tmpFile.close();
     ObjectMediaPlayer->MP->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile(QDir::toNativeSeparators(tmpFile.fileName())));
     ObjectMediaPlayer->MP->setVolume(50);
     ObjectMediaPlayer->MP->play();
}
```